# Pass props to image url but also use objectFit

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

React newbie here,
I want to pass image url as props for backGround image but also want to apply css on image to "fill".
I got how to pass for inline css

```
 style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + props.imgURL + ")" }}
```

I dunno how to apply css for this. I want to apply objectFit:fill
maybe
`style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + props.img + ")"  objectFit="fill"}}`
lol

(OR IS THERE A WAY TO PASS PROPS TO STYLESHEET. )
{HELP}

Comment: [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try this bud

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.imgURL})`}}
```

I'd try and steer away from inline styling if possible, the only time I would ever use it is for background images, just target the element in CSS to add the `object-fit` property :)

Also for future reference, this is a template literal. You can find a more info on it from [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're dealing with an object you need to separate key-value pairs with a comma. The other problem is that `object-fit` doesn't work if you use the `backgroundImage` style property to set the image instead of using `src`. So I recommend using `backgroundSize: 'contain'` instead.

```
<img
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${imgUrl})`,
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
  }}
  width="400"
  height="400"
/>
```

The image needs to have a width and height. Change my example to fit your needs.